# Program shows TypeError while passing a dictionary into a function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f(**kwargs):
   print(kwargs)

d = {'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c', '3': 'd'}   
f(**d)   # {'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c', '3': 'd'}

d = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}   
f(**d)   # TypeError: f() keywords must be strings
```

Here,I am getting the TypeError while changing the dictionary key value to int type.
May i know, why i am getting this error?

Comment: Why are you using `**`? The `**` expands the dictionary to keyword arguments, and as the error suggests, these must be strings (try `f(0='a', 1='b')` and you'll get the exact same error). Just do `f(d)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem in the second case is that you're doing the equivalent of

```
f(0 = 'a', 1 = 'b', 2 = 'c', 3 = 'd')
```

which does not make much sense since (as reported in the error) variables identifiers cannot be named using only numbers. A function expects a correct variable identifier but you are using numbers and thus raises an error.

Comment: So if i want to print the dictionary in 2nd case through a function, then how can i able to do?

Comment: Just pass the dictionary `f(dictionary)` and the function `f` is defined as `def f(d): print(d) `